# Variable to track on click

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The source code has this option

```
<div class="mydiv">
<p><img alt="" src="/images/img1.png" /></p> <
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
<p><img alt="" src="/images/img2.png" /></p> 
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
<p><img alt="" src="/images/img3.png" /></p> 
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>
```

I have enabled a trigger for onclick event and it works. However I would like to track the src if the user clicks to a specific link. Using Jquery it is possible with this:

```
$('a[href="www.outboundlink.com"]').on("click", function() {
    src = $(this).closest(".mydiv").find("img").attr("src");
});
```

However when I go to include this code to a Custom JS variable with this:

```
function {
$('a[href="www.outboundlink.com"]').on("click", function() {
    src = $(this).closest(".mydiv").find("img").attr("src");
});
return src;
}
```

When I click to the link the variable is undefined.

How can I make it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing here, but 'src' is out of scope when you return it in your last code block.

Comment: Maybe the event handler is attached before the DOM is rendered so there simply is no match for the selector ? If that is the case event delegation should help, i.e. something like $( ".mydiv" ).on( "click", "a", function( event )  to attach the click to links that are inserted into the DOM after the GTM code fired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you are trying to do here, I think your question needs some more details, but this could be a solution:

```
$('a[href="www.outboundlink.com"]').on("click", function() {
    src = $(this).closest(".mydiv").find("img").attr("src");

    pageTracker._setCustomVar(
      1,          // This custom var is set to slot #1.
      "img-src",  // The name of the custom variable
      src,        // The value of the custom variable
      3           // Sets the scope to page-level.  Optional.
    );
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
});
```

Comment: He is trying to find the source of an image that is contained in the same block (i.e. a div with the class "myDiv") as the clicked link.  So the part that needs to be addressed is the jQuery selector, not the GA tracking.

Comment: @EikePierstorff. He states that his penultimate code block (the bit that finds the source of the image) does work, and it looks like it would. His last code block makes no sense at all, and introduces a variable in to the global namespace. So I think he is having trouble with the analytics and not with finding the source of the image.